# Yaml based pipeline - setting the pool name at run time from the drop down

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have this yaml, how can I set the pool to the value selected in the drop down list?  Obviously what I have now doesn't work.  It complains that the template expression is not allowed in this context.

```
parameters:
- name: InstallNodeJS
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  type: boolean
  default: false

- name: AgentPoolSelector
  displayName: Select Agent Pool
  type: string
  default: Default
  values:
   - Default
   - Cloud
   - Dev Machines

variables:
  custom.branch: 'my-branch'
  
pool:
  name: $ {{ parameters.AgentPoolSelector }}

steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.InstallNodeJS, true) }}:
     - template: templates/nodejs-install.yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my test, to set the Pool name based on [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) we should insert the pool into one job/stage-level. You can try this format to resolve the issue:

```
parameters:
- name: InstallNodeJS
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  type: boolean
  default: false

- name: AgentPoolSelector
  displayName: Select Agent Pool
  type: string
  default: Default
  values:
   - Default
   - Cloud
   - Dev Machines

variables:
  custom.branch: 'my-branch'
  
jobs:
- job:
  displayName: FirstJob
  pool: 
    name: ${{ parameters.AgentPoolSelector }}
  steps:
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.InstallNodeJS, true) }}:
      - template: templates/nodejs-install.yml
```