# Azure DevOps Pipelines - Setting pool name from the template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to figure out how to update the pool name from the parameters using `parameters.deploymentPool`; Setting the pool name to : `name: ${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}` doesn't work; However, when I go thought the variable it works fine; Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591064/yaml-based-pipeline-setting-the-pool-name-at-run-time-from-the-drop-down), not sure if the stages has anything to do with the issue at hand

```
parameters:
  - name: deploymentPool
    type: string
    default: Pool A
    displayName: Select pool
    values:
    - Pool A

    variables: 
      AzureDevopsPool: ${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}
    
    stages:
      - stage: Stage 1
        jobs:
          - job: job 1
            pool: 
              name: '$(AzureDevopsPool)'
```

Comment: Try changing it to name: ${{ variables.AzureDevopsPool }}? if you're accessing value in variables

Comment: It does not work; it's like the variable is empty, getting No agents in pool xxxx are currently able to service this request; I am really not sure why using '$(AzureDevopsPool)' works. It should be the same as ${{ variables.AzureDevopsPool }} or  ${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}; perhaps it's a scope thing

Comment: try just pool: ${{ variables.AzureDevopsPool }} without specifying the name. look here for specifying a pool with no demands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines. It might just be being fussy about this

Comment: Tried that too … No luck;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the YAML Sample you shared, it seems like it has some issues with character indentation.

Test to use the **${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}** to set the pool name in the  job level and it can work as expected.

Refer to the sample:

```
parameters:
  - name: deploymentPool
    type: string
    default: Pool A
    displayName: Select pool
    values:
    - Pool A
    - default
    
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    pool: 
     name: ${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}
    steps:
      - script: echo "test"
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

> No agents in pool xxxx are currently able to service this request

For this issue, the value of the variable should be passed to the pool name field successfully.

It encountered a problem when running in the specified Pool. It should have nothing to do with the YAML code itself.

The issue could be related to the self-hosted agent itself.

You can consider upgrading the Self-hosted Agents to newer version and check if it can work.

For more information, you can refer to this ticket: [Azure DevOps agent not picking up yml based jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582424/azure-devops-agent-not-picking-up-yml-based-jobs)

Answer (score 1):

I have test your case and provide several ways to refer the **parameters** or **variables** . I have only test one pool name as sample.

```
parameters:
- name: deploymentPool
  type: string
  displayName: Select pool
  values:
  - 'Azure Pipelines'
  default: 'Azure Pipelines'

variables: 
  AzureDevopsPool: ${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}
  testPool: Azure Pipelines

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    pool: 
      name: ${{ variables.AzureDevopsPool }}
    steps:
    - script: | 
        echo 'test in job1 in stage1'

- stage: stage2
  jobs:
  - job: job2
    pool: 
      name: $(testPool)
    steps:
    - script: | 
        echo 'test in job2 in stage2'

- stage: stage3
  jobs:
  - job: job3
    pool: 
      name: $(AzureDevopsPool)
    steps:
    - script: | 
        echo 'test in job3 in stage3'

- stage: stage4
  jobs:
  - job: job4
    pool: 
      name: ${{ parameters.deploymentPool }}
    steps:
    - script: | 
        echo 'test in job4 in stage4'
```

[image]

notes:

1. Parameters can be added to anywhere in pipeline.
2. You should make clean the runtime and compile-time in coding a yaml to avoid confusing